# Uncaught ReferenceError: "functionName"is not defined when using in "a" tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am calling a java script function in href tag but it is showing error of undefined function. I also tried using calling jquery click function using id of anchor tag but it is not giving any response.

```
<a href="javascript:ViewCustormerdeee({{$user->id}});">
  <span id="viewCustomer" class="fa fa-eye"></span>
</a>
<script>
  function ViewCustormerdeee(id) {
    console.log(123);
  }
</script>
```

It should log `123` in the console, but it is showing error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ViewCustormerdeee is not defined

Comment: why dont you use onClick event instead.

Comment: Most likely the function is not defined in the global scope. I'd suggest both fixing the problem and modernising the logic by attaching the event using `addEventListener()` instead.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan — It's at the top level of a `<script>` element.

Comment: True, but I suspect that the OP has restructured the logic to display in the question. If this really was the case, it would work: https://jsfiddle.net/namztkwj/

Comment: You should provide a [mcve]. The laravel code is irrelevant. Show us just HTML and JS.

Comment: <a href="javascript:ViewCust();" >click</a>
function ViewCust()
{
    console.log(123);
}
here it is simple html and javascript @Quentin

Comment: @WaqasAltaf — Edit the question, don't just paste code into a comment. Provide a [mcve]. Note "complete". As pointed out by Rory, the relation of the JS to the script tags is important. The code you just shared just displays the JS: https://jsbin.com/ruduhipija/edit?html,output

Comment: i found that in that code of any jqury or javascript function are not working, even with  button on click can any one found the solution. all function are working on other pages.

Answer (score -1):

I'd personally do it this way.

`onClick=` is outdated and should be avoided.

I reckon the best way to do this would be to use an eventlistener on the element.

```html
    <a id="viewCustomerButton" href="javascript:void(0)">
      <span id="viewCustomer" class="fa fa-eye"></span>
    </a>
    <script>
      function ViewCustormerdeee(id) {
        let button = document.getElementById('viewCustomerButton');
        button.addEventListener('click', function() {
            console.log('123');
        });
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    <a onclick="ViewCustormerdeee('"+ {{$user->id}} +"');" ><span id="viewCustomer" class="fa fa-eye"></span></a>

    <script>
       function ViewCustormerdeee(id)
        {
           console.log(id);
        }
    </script>
```

Read more on this event here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: `{{$user->id}}` is laravel template code which is converted to something else server side. It isn't intended to be consumed by the browser.

Comment: Also `onclick` itself is outdated and should be avoided where possible.

Comment: so what will be the Good idea to use to call function at <a> tag @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: In plain JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener, in jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/on